# Almost Everywhere Convergence of Walsh Series of $L^2$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis

I am currently reading the Hunt's papar (http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1970.2/Main/icm1970.2.0655.0662.ocr.pdf), and am wondering if there is some notes which presents his argument more comprehensively.

Thank you.